# Writing newline with Python codecs.write

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
f = codecs.open('import.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')

for x in list:
    string = "Hello"
    f.write(string+'\n')

f.close()
```

For some reason this code does not write newlines to the file, as it would do if I had used the `open` function instead of `codecs.open`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print to UTF-8 encoded file, with platform-dependent newlines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941988/print-to-utf-8-encoded-file-with-platform-dependent-newlines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you are talking about ... also showing you how to have a complete runnable example

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open('import.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
>>> f.write("hello\nworld\n")
>>> f.close()
>>> print repr(open("import.txt").read())
'hello\nworld\n'
>>>
```

based on the comments the real answer is

**DONT USE NOTEPAD**

Comment: That seems to work, but strangely enough when I open the text file in notepad there are no newlines.

Comment: Just tried notepad++, newlines do show up over there. Thanks.

Comment: notepad is basically the crapiest text editor ever concieved ... just delete it from your system

Comment: Doesn't `stdio` convert `\n` to `\r\n` if the file is open in text mode (which is the case)?

Comment: Crap, `codecs` always open the underlying stream as binary.

Comment: @user2704291: normally, `'\n'` is converted to `os.linesep` (`'\r\n'`  on Windows) during writing. [`codecs` module does not do that. Do not use it. Use `io.open` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28446305/4279)

Answer (score 3):

[`codecs.open()` does not handle newlines correctly (`'U'` mode is deprecated)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

> Underlying encoded files are always opened in binary mode. No
>   automatic conversion of '\n' is done on reading and writing.

Use builtin `open()` function instead. If you want the same code to work on both Python 2 and 3 from the same source; you could use [`io.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open).