# Reading UTF-8 file with universal newlines in Python 2

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, line-breaks

I previously used `os.open()` to read and write text files. Now I changed to use `codecs.open()` because I wanted the UTF-8 support. This works well, but this method returned a different result in Windows, because the source files uses `\r\n` line breaks. It seems to me, that with `codecs.open()` universal line breaks are not available [because it uses binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

My understanding of the problem is that `os.open()` and `codecs.open()` have each mutually exclusive features. `os.open()` in text mode has the nice feature of [universal newline mode](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/) (which in the case of reading means that it substitutes any form of line break into `\n`), whereas `codecs.open()` provides the UTF-8 support.

My goal is to read (and preferrably write) UTF-8 encoded files into a unicode string with universal line breaks. This implies that if I read two files with different line breaks the resulting strings should be identical. I want to do this using only core libraries with Python 2.6 compatibility. How do I do this in the most elegant way?

Comment: Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941988/print-to-utf-8-encoded-file-with-platform-dependent-newlines is very similar to this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`io.open()`** is the intersection of `os.open()` and `codecs.open()`.

It provides full universal newline support and a TextWrapper mode for transparent string decode/encode. I believe it's most similar to the Python 3 implementation of `open()`

The usage is the same as `codecs.open()`:

```
my_file = io.open("myfile.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
```

Text mode and universal newlines are the default options.